# How can I upgrade Windows Phone 8.0 to 8.1

Tags: 8.0

I'm using a Nokia Lumia 525, Windows Phone 8.0. But I want to upgrade to 8.1.

How do I upgrade, should I go to Nokia Service center? Is it not possible to upgrade myself (using only mobile data connection) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade over your data connection by going to Settings > Phone Update, but be warned it will use a lot of data, so you will want to make sure you have plenty if you are on a limited data plan.

Comment: ...or connect to an unmetered WiFi hotspot...

Comment: @RowlandShaw Right, but isn't that out since the question said "using only mobile data connection"?

Comment: True, but just highlighting that it would be better to do this via a WiFi hotspot, even if it's just for an hour, it may well be cheaper than doing so via a mobile connection.

Comment: Oh ok. Yeah, you're very right about that.